# Ruby hex to string conversion involving French characters

Tags: ruby, hex, data-conversion, french, ruby-smpp

This is related to ruby gem ruby-smpp, which I'm using for my project.

I have a string of bytes `\u0000\xE0\u0000\xE2\u0000\xE1\u0000\xE8\u0000\xEA\u0000\xE9\u0000\xE7`. It represents the body of a message in French received (i.e. MO, or mobile-originating) message. The actual content of this message is `àâáèêéç`. Just wondering how to convert `\u0000\xE0\u0000\xE2\u0000\xE1\u0000\xE8\u0000\xEA\u0000\xE9\u0000\xE7` to `àâáèêéç` in Ruby.

I've tried

```
["\u0000\xE0\u0000\xE2\u0000\xE1\u0000\xE8\u0000\xEA\u0000\xE9\u0000\xE7"].pack('H*')

=> "\x00\x02\x01\b\n\t\a"
```

and

```
['E0','E2','E1','E8', 'EA', 'E9', 'E7'].pack('H*')
=> "\xE0"
```

Both are wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your string is UTF-16BE encoded:

```
str = "\u0000\xE0\u0000\xE2\u0000\xE1\u0000\xE8\u0000\xEA\u0000\xE9\u0000\xE7"

str.encode('UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE')
#=> "àâáèêéç"
```

Comment: What tells you it's UTF-16BE encoded (from someone who knows nothing of encoding)?

Comment: @CarySwoveland (1) because the values looked like _words_ (0x00E0, 0x00E2, ...), i.e. 16-bit values, and (2) because 0xE0 (224) is the codepoint for `à` in Unicode.

Comment: I see there's a lazy-person's way of answering my question: `Encoding.list.find { |e| 
str.encode('UTF-8', e) == "àâáèêéç" rescue nil } #=> #<Encoding:UTF-16BE>`. See [Encoding#list](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Encoding.html). Note: `Encoding.list.size #=> 101`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I know that way ... quicker, easier, more seductive :-)